# C# - Using WebChart.dll 

Tags: c#

Iam developing an application where I try to use WebChart.dll to create charts. I have added a reference to WebChart.dll in my application and where I try to use it it dose not work. I try to import the namespace `using WebChart;` and get: **The type or namespace name 'WebChart' could not be found (are you missing a using derective or and assembly reference**

Comment: You said, that you already added a reference to WebChart.dll to you application. If so, you could use the Object Explorer to browse it, maybe it uses other namespaces.

Comment: Click Edit and Remove the solved from your title. Remove (Or copy) your solution from the question and post it yourself as an answer. If you feel it completely solves your problem then accept your own answer by click the big Check button (it then turns green)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that WebChart.dll was not compatible with .NET Framework 4.0, changing my application to 3.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem was a .Net versioning problem, then the problem is probably that  WebChart.dll links to specific versions of .net assemblies.

You can work out what assemblies WebChart.dll links to using a tool like Reflector (free alternatives are available apparently!)

You can override this behavior if you want to by using `bindingRedirect` in your web.config file - e.g. here's a section I used in [an old DNN installation](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2009/10/dnn-installing-ajaxtoolkit-ahead-of.html)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

More on bindingRedirect - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/01/30/introduction-to-versioning-and-bindingredirect.aspx